# Tally XML API Authentication

Tags: xml, authentication, postman, tally

I need help with Tally XML API authentication.
I have tally.net ID.

But I don't know how to authenticate my XML API call using this tally.net ID and password.
Specifically I am looking at the XML tags in which this information will be sent.

Tally only mentions a Tally Authentication SDK for mobile devices but not for web applications.

Every time I make a call to tally from Postman I get user is not authorized exception as I think I am not sending my Tally.net ID.

Comment: What is the error code? https://help.tallysolutions.com/docs/td9rel54/auth-lib/#gref

Comment: post the xml you are using